# How do I use a jQuery libary in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-core, jquery-plugins

I am developing a website using ASP.NET Core 2.2, and mainly with razor pages.

I am trying to make a tree table and found a jQuery plugin that suits perfectly but I am unsure of how to use it in a good way.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Tree-Table-Plugin-Bootstrap-GTreeTable.html

this is the plugin I want to use, and I have no idea where to start.

We are using areas as well so I guess this makes the pathing a bit different? 
Do I just put the scripts in the root folder?

Comment: https://gijgo.com/tree/demos/bootstrap-4-treeview
I have tried this as well, I was able to install it with the NPM but it still doesnt work, so I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

In general, static files you need to reference, such as scripts simply need to go into your `wwwroot` directory. Once published, this will map to your document root, so you basically ignore the `wwwroot` part when referencing the static resources, i.e.: `~/lib/jquery/jquery.js`.

By convention, "library" files - stuff you didn't write yourself - go in the `wwwroot/lib` directory. As such, you could literally just download your plugin and put some place like `wwwroot/lib/jquery-treeview`. Then, you just need to add the appropriate static references (i.e. `link`/`script` tags) in your view according to the documentation for that library.

However, done manually that way, you are then responsible to keep it up to date and available yourself. It's also typical to ignore `wwwroot/lib` in source control, since those libraries will generally be brought in by some other means, and you don't want to be committing third-party code into your own repositories. That creates a problem with the manual approach described above.

Long and short, you need to use some sort of package management tool to pull in your third party libraries into `wwwroot/lib`. Originally, that was `bower` and Visual Studio had built-in support with a GUI and everything. Later, though, `bower` ended development. Microsoft has since responded by adding in what they call [`LibMan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) (short literally for "Library Manager"). You can certainly use this if you want, it's lacking in many ways. Chief among its failings is its reliance on cdnjs as a library source. If the library happens to be hosted on cdnjs, you're fine, but if you need a library that isn't, then you're out of luck and back to the same problem of how to properly manage your that library and any other unsupported libraries.

The better approach is to use the `npm` package manager, but this takes a bit more effort. The biggest roadblock is that node packages are added to the infamous `node_modules` directory, which is not served by default. Some might recommend that you simply add this directory to the static files middleware as well, but that's a mistake. The directory is not meant to be served and should not be served.

Instead, you'll need something like [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), or even just plain [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts). With any other those, you can create "build" scripts that be utilized to, among other things, move libraries from `node_modules` to your `wwwroot/lib` directory, selectively, including only select files thereof.

How to set all that up is dependent upon which tool you decide to go with and is subsequently far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. Microsoft has some basic documentation ([grunt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-grunt?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [gulp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-gulp?view=aspnetcore-2.2)), but beyond that, Google is your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

May I ask, if I add it manually to the root folder, and don't really care about keeping those plugins up to date, are there any other problems to worry about?

I will certainly look into grunt as I have read some about it.

Comment: Well, the main issue is source control. Like I said, the `wwwroot/lib` folder should be ignored, so you aren't keeping a bunch of third-party code in your own repository. However, you can simply put the plugin somewhere else in `wwwroot` for now. I'd still encourage you to just go ahead and get yourself oriented now. Doing stuff temporarily until you amass some future set of knowledge is a form of technical debt, and you'll likely not revisit it.